# How to hide empty <span> in IE in javascript. (Note work fine in other browser)

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm having a issue in IE with that simple piece of code. 
I'm using this code to display and hide error message under the field where it happen.

```
function validateStuff(field, msg)
{
    var regex=/^\d{1,7}$/;
    var id= field.name + ".error";
    if (!regex.test(field.value))
    {
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML= msg;
      return false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML= "";
        return true;
    }
}
```

the span look like this

```
<SPAN ID="field.error" CLASS="regred"></SPAN>
```

This code work fine in chrome & Firefox but IE after the validation is run it's show a big empty block.

I've tried display:none

```
function validateStuff(field, msg)
{
    var regex=/^\d{1,7}$/;
    var id= field.name + ".error";
    if (!regex.test(field.value))
    {
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML= msg;
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline-block';
      return false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML= "";
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        return true;
    }
}
```

the span block is still there.

I've tried removing the span

```
function validateStuff(field, msg)
{
    var regex=/^\d{1,7}$/;
    var id= field.name + ".error";
    if (!regex.test(field.value))
    {
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML= msg;
      return false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML= "";
        //IE shenanigan
        var parentNode = document.getElementById(id).parentNode;
        parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById(id));
        return true;
    }
}
```

but the span still show when in other browser it hide has expected.

Why ?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Have you tried using a `.display = "inline"` versus `inline-block`?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using ? I think IE8 had problems with span and display:none

Comment: you are correct I'm using IE8 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hiding you can put it out of the viewport.

```
function validateStuff(field, msg)
{
    var regex=/^\d{1,7}$/;
    var id= field.name + ".error";
    var el = document.getElementById(id); 

    if (!regex.test(field.value))
    {
      el.innerHTML= msg;
      el.style.display = 'inline-block';
      el.style.position = 'static'; 
      el.style.left = '0px'; 
      return false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        el.innerHTML= "";
        el.style.position = 'absolute';
        el.style.left = '-10000px'; 

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seem to work the first time but when there is another error in the field it give a javascript error at el.style.position = 'initial';

Comment: Try with static instead.